# SVN merge: newly added file is ignored from new directory

Tags: svn, merge

I have 2 commits in my trunk

**commit x:** added a new directory

**commit y** added a new file to the directory added via commit x

Now i merge both these revisions to a branch

```
svn merge -cx,y <trunk path>
```

As a result of merge, i get the new directory in branch and not the new file added to it.

Please someone explain me what went wrong

Comment: Did you try to specify multiple changes? -c x -c y?

Comment: I merge them both in single attempt, not individually